# get_python().system not recognized in PyCharm (TensorFlow Object Detection API)

Tags: pycharm, ipython, tensorflow2.0

Sorry for silly question - however, I was trying to run the TensorFlow's Object_Detection code in PyCharm (converted the Jupyter Notebook - which was working). I initially had problems with ipython, but after installing and adding this package (Settings>Project>Projec Interpreter> (+)Add) it would recognize the
get_ipython import, but when it hits a system call (**e.g get_ipython().system('pip install -U --pre tensorflow=="2.*"'**) - it would throw the following error:

**get_ipython().system('pip install -U --pre tensorflow=="2.*"')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'system'**

I assume that there is something else not set up, and most likely something silly. It works when I do the commands in the console on a line-by-line basis, but not from the editor.

I am using PyCharm Community 2020.1, Python 3.8(64bit), IPython v17.18.1, TensorFlow2.0

EDIT this code was sourced from : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb
There was a comment about using it outside of the Colab environment (however the link was broken)

Comment: Is this your code or it's 3rd party? Where is this code called? If you want to install a new dependency (TensorFlow), do it via Settings -> Python Interpreter -> [+] -> Tensorflow or do that manually in a Terminal

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. This was direct out of the TensorFlow install (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb). There's a note for running it locally, however the link is broken, so I don't know what was there. As I said - it works from the console, but not when I try to run from the editor.